# Efficiently iterate multiple maps with the same keys

Tags: c++, optimization, dictionary, iteration

If I have two maps which are guaranteed to have exactly the same set of keys, how can I efficiently iterate through both maps?

For example, say I have the following maps:

```
std::map<std::string, int> iMap;
std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > vMap;
```

At some point they both end up with exactly the same set of keys. I now need to update all values of `vMap` based on the corresponding `iMap` value. The first thing that comes to mind is something this:

```
typedef map<string, int> map_t;
BOOST_FOREACH(map_t::value_type &p, iMap) {
  vMap[p.first].push_back(p.second);
}
```

However, it seems rather wasteful that we have to lookup each value of `vMap[n]` considering we're effectively going through the keys in order. Is there any way we can take advantage of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure that the keys are identical, you can iterate over both maps in lockstep:

```
auto it1 = iMap.begin();
auto it2 = vMap.begin();

while (it1 != iMap.end())
{
    it2->second.push_back(*it1);
    ++it1;
    ++it2;
}
```